# Do regular animals exist in the Pokémon universe?

Tags: pokemon

I've never really played the games, but I catch a lot of the cartoons when my kids watch them.
I've noticed that I never see any regular animals in the cartoons; only pokémon.

So my question is, do regular animals even exist in the *Pokémon* universe?

Are they ever seen directly in the cartoons?

Comment: Yes, bloody hundreds; http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Animals_in_the_Pok%C3%A9mon_world

Comment: See also http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/27455/13855 "Are there ever any animals featured that aren't Pokémon?" on Anime and Manga SE (thanks to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/6006/ankit-sharma for the tip). See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71564/4918 In “The Matrix”, why are there no animals?

Comment: In my opinion the anime is an unpleasant balancing act between "we don't want to accept the implications of animals not existing, but we also don't want to show animals".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Animals are mentioned many times in the series [as documented here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Animals_in_the_Pok%C3%A9mon_world). These are usually just mentioned in passing or indirectly. The main purpose of real animals seems to be for food for humans.

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7XTmMa9D_s) around the 3:45 mark you can hear Brock and Ash advertising

> french-fried flounder, seven-layered crab cakes, squid on a
>   stick, and clam juice snow cones.

Also, here is Ash dressed in a cow costume.

[image]

Comment: wouldn't that be a Miltank costume?

Comment: @costrom doesn't appear to be... black/white vs pink/black, longer horns, nose ring...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've been answered, but I would add that - to my knowledge - the Pokémon actually *seen* are usually bugs or fish, and references to larger, more complex animals are from the first season, where they were going with the idea that Pokémon was set in the real world. After a while they veered away from that and started saying instead that it was its own world, and the references to animals stopped.