# Are there any mundane animals in "Pokémon Detective Pikachu"?

Tags: pokemon, pokemon-detective-pikachu

There are a [considerable number of mundane animals seen in other parts of the Pokémon franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127252/do-regular-animals-exist-in-the-pok%C3%A9mon-universe), but are there any seen (or referred to) in the world of [*Pokémon Detective Pikachu?*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5884052/)

I'm happy to accept direct evidence such as pictures of them, or indirect evidence such as diner menus or food outlets.

Comment: lol. Just looking at the film now. They have Pret a Manger and Anne Summers in Ryme City.

Comment: One of the market stalls seems to sell sizzle steaks (or strips)  but it does not say what kind of steaks/strips

Comment: In the anime, people are [known to eat Farfetch'd](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Farfetch%27d_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Pok.C3.A9dex_entries) and [Magikarp](https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/f/f4/Edible_Magikarp.png), at least in the early seasons. Lately though, pretty much all Pokémon can eat fruits and berries, and any meat shown from an unknown source. That doesn't answer the question, but it shows how the anime dealt with it.

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101456/are-there-any-normal-animals-in-pokemon-universe

Answer (score 3):

**Although no mundane animals are *featured* in the film, there was an indication in the opening sequence that Pokémon may coexist with real-world animals.**

The ancient Egyptian hieroglyphs seen at the start of the film replace many of the symbols with stylised versions of pokémon but we can still see the classic scarab and ibis symbols. Although there are pokémon that do mildly resemble these creatures (especially [Heracross](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Heracross_(Pok%C3%A9mon))), there aren't any that are sufficiently close that we'd expect to see these symbols *unchanged*.

[image]

Comment: Those are just Pokémon that haven't been introduced yet.

Comment: Real animals used to exist but Pokémon drove them to extinction.

Comment: @Adamant - you can't just invent Pokémon to solve all of your problems. Unless you're Nintendo

Comment: How do you know that these are not just fantasy creatures, the same way that people in our own world have drawn hippogriffs, centaurs, and sasquatches?

Comment: @RobertColumbia - While that's not untrue, the fact that they're identical to mundane creatures found in our world is a very strong indication that they're the same as the mundane creatures found in our world. Occam's Razor tells us not to create unnecessary postulates. If it looks like an ibis, it's probably an ibis rather than a mythical ibis-like creature